# MySQL-query to retrieve MAX-value doesnt work for decimal numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

```
 id    layer    l_to    blank
 1     1        10      xyz
 0     0        5.5     xyz
```

I want to get the highest number of column-variable "l_to" that shares column-variable "blank".

I have tried the following SQL-query:

```
 SELECT MAX(l_to), COUNT(layer),l_from FROM layers WHERE blank='xyz'
```

This works fine, if "l_to" of *layer 1* is below 10. If it is ten, the query returns "l_to" from *layer 0* (5.5).

Any Idea for why this is, and how can I retrieve the MAX?

**@EDIT: Changing Datatype of "l_to" from VARCHAR to DECIMAL (5,1) got me the desired result. Thanks for the answers!**

Comment: Sounds like you are getting the max of a string. What is the datatype of `l_to`?

Comment: Looks like the `l_to` column datatype is string, not number. Try `MAX(l_to + 0)`

Comment: Please share more details, like the `CREATE` statement of that table

Comment: @HoneyBadger datatype is varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datatype is not a number for field l_to so 5 is greater than 1 for a string. Probably a varchar. Change field  l_to to a Decimal [1].

Only consider casting if you do not have control over the table structure as best practice is the data type reflects the data use in the world. This protects the data integrity of the database, provides helpful functions related to the datatype and ensures intuitive outcomes, like Max function. Casting as a work around for this query will only lead to downstream issues; refactor the structure now if you can.

Reference

1. Decimal data type suggested in comments by @Akina. Originally suggested float, but Decimal appears to reflect the Use Case better than float, given the limited examples shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LIMIT` query, and also cast the `l_to` column to decimal:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM layers
WHERE blank = 'xyz'
ORDER BY CAST(l_to AS DECIMAL(12.4)) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: *CAST(l_to AS SIGNED)* The values may be not integer (see sample).

Answer (score 0):

Cast l_to from string to decimal

```
SELECT MAX(cast(l_to as DECIMAL(10,2)), COUNT(layer) from FROM layers WHERE blank='xyz'
```